# How to show different results in mysql search with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am not a programmer,I am trying to learn some coding,I have used some same codes to search MySQL and show result in my page,if the PHP code doesn't find a value in mysql,it shows no result.I want to show my custom message to this condition, if there is no value in mysql for 'serialno' value i need to show "xxx" msg

my code is this

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
<?php
$db_hostname = 'localhost';
$db_username = 'XXX';
$db_password = 'XXX';
$db_database = 'XXX';

// Database Connection String
$con = mysqli_connect($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password);
mysqli_query ($con, "set character_set_client='utf8'");
mysqli_query ($con, "set character_set_results='utf8'");

//  mysqli_query ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
 if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
  }

mysqli_select_db($con, $db_database);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>جستجوی شماره سریال</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
<form class="form-wrapper cf" action="" method="post">
<div class="byline"><p style="direction: rtl">شماره سریال دستگاه را وارد کنید :</p></div>
<input type="text" name="term" />
<button type="submit">جستجو</button>
</form>
    </body>

<?php
if (!empty($_REQUEST['term'])) {

$term = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST['term']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM serial WHERE serialno = ".$term;
$r_query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r_query)){
/* echo '<br /> ID: ' .$row['id']; */
echo '<div style="direction: rtl"><font size="12"'." face='Tahoma'>";
echo '<br /> شماره سریال: '.$row['serialno'];
echo '<br />تامین کننده: '.$row['vendor'];
echo '<br /> وضعیت: '.$row['stat'];
echo '</div>';
}

}
?>
    </body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysqli_num_rows(query); which will return number of rows query returns and then write an if function to display message.

```
    if (!empty($_POST['term'])) {

       $term = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['term']);
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM serial WHERE serialno = ".$term;
       $r_query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
       $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($r_query); //Number of rows query returned

       if($num_rows > 0) { //Here you check if that number is higher then 0 you go with the loop

       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r_query)){
       /* echo '<br /> ID: ' .$row['id']; */
       echo '<div style="direction: rtl"><font size="12"'." face='Tahoma'>";
       echo '<br /> شماره سریال: '.$row['serialno'];
       echo '<br />تامین کننده: '.$row['vendor'];
       echo '<br /> وضعیت: '.$row['stat'];
       echo '</div>';
      }

      } else {
       //Here you display your message
      }
```

Also this is open for SQL injection attack, so PDO would be a better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to display a message to the user when 'serialno' has no value?

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r_query)){
    if(isset($row['serialno'])){
        /* echo '<br /> ID: ' .$row['id']; */
        echo '<div style="direction: rtl"><font size="12"'." face='Tahoma'>";
        echo '<br /> شماره سریال: '.$row['serialno'];
        echo '<br />تامین کننده: '.$row['vendor'];
        echo '<br /> وضعیت: '.$row['stat'];
        echo '</div>';
    }else{
        echo "No value in serialno";
    }
}
```

Or if you still want to show the rest of the row:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r_query)){
    /* echo '<br /> ID: ' .$row['id']; */
    echo '<div style="direction: rtl"><font size="12"'." face='Tahoma'>";
    echo '<br /> شماره سریال: '.(isset($row['serialno'])?$row['serialno']:"Row has serialno");
    echo '<br />تامین کننده: '.$row['vendor'];
    echo '<br /> وضعیت: '.$row['stat'];
    echo '</div>';
}
```

But you should really use PDO ;)

Comment: This page isn’t working  is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: With both snippets?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 if (!empty($_REQUEST['term'])) { 
   $term = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST['term']);
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM serial WHERE serialno = ".$term;
   $r_query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

   if( mysqli_num_rows($r_query) > 0  )
   {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r_query)){
       /* echo '<br /> ID: ' .$row['id']; */
       echo '<div style="direction: rtl"><font size="12"'." face='Tahoma'>";
       echo '<br /> شماره سریال: '.$row['serialno'];
       echo '<br />تامین کننده: '.$row['vendor'];
       echo '<br /> وضعیت: '.$row['stat'];
       echo '</div>';
      }
   }
   else{
    echo "<p>YOUR CUSTOM MESSAGE</p>";
   } 
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

it's better to use PDO 
[enter link description here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

whit this way you will get a lot of problems

Comment: While I agree that it's better to use PDO, this should have been a comment and not an answer.

Comment: since i need it for a very simple project and im not a programmer i need a more simple way.

Comment: @wilson well wilson, PDO isn't just 'better'. It's much safer and a lot of people would say that it's also easier. So I really recommend using PDO.